# Find a permutation $\sigma$ maximizing the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n {a_i \over \sigma(i)}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, permutations

> Given  $$a_1< a_2<\dots <  a_n,$$
>
> find a permutation $\sigma$ maximizing the sum >$$\sum_{i=1}^n {a_i \over \sigma(i)}.$$

I can't figure our where to begin. I know that the solution is $\sigma=e$, but I cannot prove it.

Comment: Maybe worth trying: without loss of generality, assume the $a_i$'s are non-decreasing, and use the rearrangement inequality?

Comment: After the edit, and to provide more details to my previous comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality

Comment: For the answer to be $\sigma=e$, I think you need $a_1>a_2>\cdots>a_n$.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information. I edited it.

Comment: Imagine $a_n$ is huge compared to the other terms. Then the maximum sum will certainly have $\sigma(n)=1$